# Match numbers in Column and copy corresponding value to a new column

Tags: excel, text, excel-formula, phone-number, words

I have 4 coloumns in single excel sheet  `A,B,C,D`.

```
column A contains  digits in thousands (22300) rows (not in sequence)

column B contains  a value ( words) (sorted as A to Z )

Column c contains the same numbers as column A but not in sequence

column D contains nothing
```

I need a formula to look up at `column C` and match that number in `column A` ,and take the corresponding value from `column B` and copy it in 
`column D`.

```
A         B        c         D
234567    local    234567    local
```

the rows are in thousands, it is very tedius and tiring to lookup such a huge number any help would be appreciated.

Comment: no,,,i did not have any formula to show,,,i am not well versed with excel formula !

Comment: feel free to mark my answer as your solution if it helped you

Comment: If Column C=Column A then why the match?  or are you saying that column A and C has the same set of numbers but not in the same order?

Answer (score 1):

Place in D2 and copy it down:

```
=INDEX(B:B,MATCH(C2,A:A,0))
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need is `VLOOKUP`:

Place in `D1` that formula and drag it down:

```
=VLOOKUP(C1;$A$21115:$B$21115;2;FALSE)
```

Works with german formula:

[image]